# Make a wide power connector fit in a narrow slot

Tags: electrical, lighting

This seems like a bad idea but I wanted to know for sure. I am trying to extend the reach of my Christmas lights this year into a garden that is about 6 feet from my fence. I don't want to have lights on the ground as my kids would try to play with them. Same logic if I tried to brace them in the air from the fence into the garden.

Light connectors, all of the ones I purchase anyway, have the two narrow power connectors. All the groundless extension cords I find have the narrow and wide connectors which means I cannot use it to extend the lights.

What I *could* do is use wire cutters or a dremel to trim the wide connector down to size. Again I could see that being a bad idea if I was to try and use that cable for anything else.

What are my options here assuming I cannot find the right extension cable?

Comment: I hope this is on a GFCI circuit or a GFCI extension cord, the plugs are made that way so they can only be plugged in the correct way. On screw in lights this puts the 115v on the center, if reversed the shell is hot and a possible shock hazard

Comment: How about just running a long extension cord from the outlet to where you want the extended set of lights to be instead of using the power connector on the end of the lights to extend them? You're right that modifying an extension cord is the wrong thing to do, purposely defeating safety mechanisms makes you responsible for any injury or death that results. Even if you're sure that _you_ would never use that extension cord with a polarized device, you can't be sure that someone else won't use it for something else next Christmas.

Comment: LED chains don't care... I presume you want the extenxion between one light chain and another, given that narrow/narrow will plug into wide/narrow. Inknow what I'd do -- use a grounded cord with a grounded-to-ungrounded cheater adapter,  if those still exist -- but I hesitate to recommend that. Or just use another chain of lights as your extension cord.

Comment: @keshlam Yes. I want to connect another set of LED's but I cannot, in my case, use a set of lights as the extension for reasons I gave in the question.

Comment: Do not! Repete, Do not clip or in any other way "modify" you electrical connections unless you hire a licensed electrician to do the work to code. There is a reason plugs and receptacles have developed from simple 2 blades of the same size and shapes from years ago to a safer "polarized" 2 nonsymmetrical prongs or three pronged plugs and receptacles. The newer polarized system prevents electrical currents from flowing along improper paths that could result in injury or death. By making improper modifications to any electrical device you not only expose yourself and your loved ones to electrica

Comment: @user76215 -- that sort of device modification is *beyond the scope of Code*.

Comment: Light connectors (on the strings, I presume) have _NARROW_ blades. Extension cords have a _wide_ and _narrow_ slot. How will two _narrow_ blades not fit into a wide & narrow receptacle? Very confused.

Answer (score 2):

I might get some flack for this answer, but if you are only connecting a set of mini Christmas lights to another set, this should be fine.  I had to do it as well...

For those that don't know, mini light sets have a male plug on one end and a female plug on the other so you can string several strands of lights together.  Unlike every other extension cord sold, a light set has two narrow blades on the male end and two narrow slots on the female end.  This means that polarity doesn't matter at all, and has the bonus effect of making sure you only plug another polarity-doesn't-matter strand into the end.

All cheap extension cords that I could find have one wide blade and one narrow, so if you need a "gap" between strands of lights, you're out of luck.  Unless you have a Dremel or wire cutters or even a decent file to make one of the blades narrow.

That said, I *only* use my modified cord with mini light sets, and I labeled it as "Christmas lights" so I don't use it for anything else.

**Disclaimer:** Modifying electrical components such as extension cords is in general, a bad idea.  They are made a certain way for a reason, and if you *think* you need to modify it, you're probably trying to do something dangerous, and there's a detail or a special part that you don't know about. In this case, the modified cord could allow a device requiring a polarized connection to be plugged in the wrong way, which is dangerous (the mini lights, as discussed, are not polarized).

Update:  I did find this [one company](http://www.elkord.com/) that sells (*not sold in stores!*) a non-polarized plug for around $12 each.  They only sell this one product...

Comment: I think giving such advice is a bad idea. Your cautioning and marking is admirable, but I don't think it is enough to justify explaining how to do it.

Comment: @JPhi1618 This is not out of the realm of normal.  You can use a non-grounded GFCI as long as you label that it is not grounded.  Why is the non-polarized plug marked for such use any different?  While not ideal, I would say the chance for danger is lower than a non-grounded GFCI.

Comment: The problem with defeating a safety measure and marking it so only _you_ will use it correctly is that you can't guarantee that someone else won't unpack the christmas lights next year (or maybe you sold the box of lights at a garage sale and forgot about your special cord) and plug in a device that relies on proper polarization, causing an electrocution hazard.

Comment: I agree with the concerns.  Adding more explicit labeling to the modified extension cord would be good enough for me: *Warning:  only for use with non-polarized devices.  Powering a polarized device with this cord is dangerous.*

Answer (score 1):

Buy non-polarized plug ends and short lengths of lamp cord and build a proper non-polarized cord.  Or buy a non-polarized extension cord.

Found [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0069VW61K). I am sure you could find the other end.  Just search "non polarized plug end"

Point is buy some parts online and just build it proper.  Your local home center might have some non-polarized plug end options.

[image]

Comment: Non-polarized plugs are common and easy to find - and are still commonly used, many plug-in lights and appliances use them. Non-polarized receptacles or in-line plugs appear to be impossible to find, I haven't found any. I believe they are still common in Japan, so can probably be imported, but they won't likely meet USA certifications.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a cheap extension chord you can just cram the wide blade into the narrow slot with brute strength. Then wrap the junction with plastic wrap to seal it from the weather.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This is a pretty dangerous idea. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

Come on.  So easy.
Just purchase a non-polarized extension cord.  It will fit between the lights sequences as it has on both ends the same small identical small blade systems.  Safe and legal.  Find one at Americord website for about $6.50.

Think about the how and why. It’s the same set up as your lights

Or just purchase some more of those cheap lights and use black electrical tape over the lights you don’t want to show between bushes e or whatever.  Additional light runs done this way may be less expensive dive than purchasing the extension cord above.

Comment: The cord has already been mentioned, but I am not sure what you are suggesting.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to force an improper plug/receptacle mismatch and I recommend you don't because of reasons I will explain later in this post. Make sure the same wire to wire connection is not reversed when you reconnect. The wire will have a ribbed insulation pattern on one side and the other will usually be smooth. Make sure the ribbed side is reconnected to the ribbed side on the other connected side. This will maintain the proper polarity just as the wider plug blade would have. The ribbed pattern may be hard to see but in bright light possibly with the aid of a magnifier you should be able to see it.

Now for the rest of the story.

Do not! Repeat, do not clip or in any other way "modify" your electrical connections unless you hire a licensed electrician to do the work to code. There is a reason plugs and receptacles have developed from simple 2 blades of the same size and shapes from years ago to a safer "polarized" 2 non-symmetrical prongs or three pronged plugs and receptacles. The newer polarized system prevents electrical currents from flowing along improper paths that could result in injury or death.

By making improper modifications to any electrical device you not only expose yourself and your loved ones to electrical hazards but you have violated the law. Your insurance company may refuse to cover any accident caused by your actions leaving you exposed to lawsuits and damages incurred because of your actions as well as possible negligent murder charges if someone should die as a result of your actions. If the plugs don't fit spend a few bucks to buy new extension cords or plugs that do fit properly. Anything you buy should have the approval of at least one of the accepted accredited testing and licensing bodies that allow electrical products to be sold in the US. And remember just because it lights up when you are done with your new "mod" DOES NOT mean that you won't!

Comment: Did you delete your post and rewrite it? You can just edit the post with the edit button below the post. I would also recommend that you use some line breaks in your post to break up the wall of text. It would make it easier to read. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Matt:  user76215 does not have enough reputation to edit his post.

Comment: The sort of work discussed here is largely *beyond the scope of the NEC*